# Add function to Dokan ajax class

Tags: plugin-development, functions, customization

I have Dokan plugin installed.
It has Dokan_Ajax class with public function add_shipping_tracking_info.

I was trying to replace that function with no luck so decided to add new function in my plugin that needs to work with ajax in Dokan.

That has not been successful either using answers from stackexchange and other places describing how to extend class.
Hope someone can point me to what I'm doing wrong.
Much appreciated.

Dokan Ajax class file:

```
    class Dokan_Ajax {

        /**
         * Singleton object
         *
         * @staticvar boolean $instance
         * @return \self
         */
        public static function init() {

            static $instance = false;

            if ( !$instance ) {
                $instance = new self;
            }

            return $instance;
        }

        /**
         * Init ajax handlers
         *
         * @return void
         */
        function init_ajax() {
            //withdraw note
            $withdraw = Dokan_Admin_Withdraw::init();

            add_action( 'wp_ajax_dokan_add_shipping_tracking_info', array( $this, 'add_shipping_tracking_info' ) );

            more add action/filters......
        }

public function add_shipping_tracking_info() {

        .... original dokan function code ....
    }
    ...... more public functions.....
    }
```

My plugin code:

```
class My_Dokan_Ajax extends Dokan_Ajax {

    function __construct() {

        add_action( 'wp_ajax_dokan_add_shipping_tracking_info', array( $this, 'OWadd_shipping_tracking_info' ) );
    }

 public static function init() {

        static $instance = false;

        if ( !$instance ) {
            $instance = new My_Dokan_Ajax();
        }

        return $instance;
    }


  /**
     * Add shipping tracking info via ajax
     */
    public function OWadd_shipping_tracking_info() {

.... my function code ....

    }
}
new My_Dokan_Ajax();
```

Second code I tried, this tries to remove existing function and add my new one:

```
class My_Dokan_Ajax extends Dokan_Ajax {

  /**
     * Add shipping tracking info via ajax
     */
    public function add_shipping_tracking_info() {

        .... my new function code ....
    }
}
remove_action( 'wp_ajax_dokan_add_shipping_tracking_info','Dokan_Ajax::add_shipping_tracking_info' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_dokan_add_shipping_tracking_info','My_Dokan_Ajax::add_shipping_tracking_info' );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the core developer of Dokan. There is a much simpler way to use your custom function for this case. This `dokan_add_shipping_tracking_info` action can be found within this template : `/rafsuntaskin.com/wp-content/plugins/dokan/templates/orders/details.php` .

You can copy this into your theme and change the action to your custom function like this : 
`rt_custom_add_shipping_tracking_info` replaces `dokan_add_shipping_tracking_info`
Then add a custom wp ajax hook in your theme's functions.php 
`wp_ajax_rt_custom_add_shipping_tracking_info` and use the custom function as callback.

Thanks